# Angular 4 (webpack) Thirs part libraries CSS are not included

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using Angular4 with webpack. Third party libraries css are not being loaded. These are the webpack.common.js and vendor.ts uploaded on Github (https://gist.github.com/shafaqkazmi/37342bee92f3ca56530c288de5b3b566).

**Version details:**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.2
@angular/compiler: 4.1.2
@angular/core: 4.1.2
@angular/forms: 4.1.2
@angular/http: 4.1.2
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.2
@angular/router: 4.1.2
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly import them, usually done either in a main scss file or main app file.

Comment: Thanks @Chase. Issue was resolved by adding JS/CSS files in `vendor.js`